# Internet Explorer 7 Crashing becasue of CSS in Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, sass, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation 3 and am trying to get it to work in Internet Explorer 7.

The error:
What happens is the page loads and renders the content fine, but then you cannot click on anything, scroll or interact at all and then Internet Explorer then stops responding.

The cause: 
I have narrowed it down to these two lines within the CSS. If I take them out then it works fine in Internet Explorer 7, but doesn't look how I would expect.

```
.c-1, .c-2, .c-3, .c-4, .c-5, .c-6, .c-7, .c-8, .c-9, .c-10, .c-11, .c-12, 
header[role="banner"] h1, header[role="banner"] nav, header[role="banner"] aside,  
div[role="main"] div#main-container, div.sub-footer aside > div, 
footer[role="contentinfo"] > .row h1, footer[role="contentinfo"] > .row .info, 
footer[role="contentinfo"] > .row nav 
{ 
    float: left; 
}

.c-1, .c-2, .c-3, .c-4, .c-5, .c-6, .c-7, .c-8, .c-9, .c-10, .c-11, .c-12,
header[role="banner"] h1, header[role="banner"] nav, header[role="banner"] aside, 
div[role="main"] div#main-container, div.sub-footer aside > div, 
footer[role="contentinfo"] > .row h1, footer[role="contentinfo"] > .row .info, 
footer[role="contentinfo"] > .row nav 
{ 
    position: relative; 
    min-height: 1px; 
    padding: 0 15px; 
}
```

The issue:
The only problem here is this code is generated by SASS using a mixin provided by Zurb Foundation, which I can't remove for the rest of the project.

I have not reached the 4096 limit on selectors for IE either, I did a count and it is under 1000.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ripping out all the HTML5 element styling and just leaving the other classes ? (.c-1 etc.). I know most browsers ignore things they don't understand but perhaps something else is going on.

Comment: @grimmus, that does seem to fix the problem. However, I am still not sure how I could fix this for just IE7 as these styles are generated by Zurb

Comment: Does Zurb allow for conditional comments ? Have you tried including a reference to HTML5Shiv. Might help render the elements easier in IE7

Comment: I do have the HTML5Shiv. I can add conditional comments within the markup but not within Zurb Foundation compiler

Comment: @imjared, they do support IE7 on older versions, version 2.2.1 does support IE7, http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/2.2.1/qa.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Zurb, but I've noticed that IE7 crashes whenever I have two elements that are directly nested one inside the other and both of which have the `min-height` property set. For example, this markup would cause IE7 to crash

```
<div style="min-height: 1px">
    <div style="min-height: 1px">
        Hello IE 7!
    </div>
</div>
```

But this would not

```
<div style="min-height: 1px">
    <div>
       Hello IE 7!
    </div>
</div>
```